# Using regrexMatch in Mongodb aggregate in Golang project

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I wrote a query in Studio3T which words as expected and now I wish to write the query into the Golang project I am working on. Bson items are still a little mysterious to me. I try to make educated guesses on where and how to use bson.A, bson.D, bson.M etc. Also the brackets aren't exactly the same from the query to goland and those too are challenging to me. The syntax is where help is truly needed.

I have:

```
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate; Tracking Number(s): AAAA-BBBB"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate; Tracking Number(s): CCCC-DDDD"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate of IP123456789; Tracking Number(s): EEEE-FFFF"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " authorizationNbr [GGGG-HHHH] INVALID: unknown origin"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " authorizationNbr [IIII-JJJJ] INVALID: unknown origin"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Unable to update, apologies . Please resubmit: AUTH_CRUD_API: %!s(<nil>)"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Unable to update, apologies . Please resubmit"
}
```

I would like:

```
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Authorization is a duplicate"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " authorizationNbr"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " authorizationNbr"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Unable to update"
}
{
    "errorMsg" : " Unable to update"
}
```

To accomplish this I wrote (I am sure some of you will have a much better way to do this but I would like to focus on writing it in my go project):

```
addFields
{
    "errorMsg": { "$cond": [{ "$regexMatch": {"input": "$errorMsg", "regex": "Authorization is a duplicate"}}, "Authorization is a duplicate", 
        {"$cond": [{ "$regexMatch": {"input": "$errorMsg", "regex": "authorizationNbr"}}, "authorizationNbr", 
            {"$cond" : [{"$regexMatch" : {"input" : "$errorMsg", "regex" : "[Uu]nable to update, apologies"}}, "Unable to update", "$errorMsg"]}]}]}
}
```

There are previous and next stages that I don't think are relevant to my question.

This is what I have in my go code:

```
addFields := bson.D{{"$addFields", bson.D{
        {"errorMsg", bson.D{{"$cond", bson.A{bson.D{{"$regexMatch", bson.A{"input": "$errorMsg", "regex": "Authorization is a duplicate"}}}, "Authorization is a duplicate",
            {"$cond", bson.A{bson.D{{"$regexMatch", bson.A{"input": "$errorMsg", "regex": "authorizationNbr"}}}, "authorizationNbr",
                {"$cond", bson.A{bson.D{{"$regexMatch", bson.A{"input": "$errorMsg", "regex": "[Uu]nable to update, apologies"}}}, "Unable to update", "$errorMsg"}}}}
            }}}},
    }}}
```

Please ask any clarifying question you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

addFields := bson.D{
    bson.E{Key: "$addFields", Value: bson.D{
        {Key: "errorMsg", Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "$cond", Value: bson.A{
                bson.D{
                    {Key: "$regexMatch", Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "input", Value: "$errorMsg"},
                        {Key: "regex", Value: primitive.Regex{Pattern: "Authorization is a duplicate"}},
                    }},
                },
                "Authorization is a duplicate",
                bson.D{
                    {Key: "$cond", Value: bson.A{
                        bson.D{
                            {Key: "$regexMatch", Value: bson.D{
                                {Key: "input", Value: "$errorMsg"},
                                {Key: "regex", Value: primitive.Regex{Pattern: "authorizationNbr"}},
                            }},
                        },
                        "authorizationNbr",
                        bson.D{
                            {Key: "$cond", Value: bson.A{
                                bson.D{
                                    {Key: "$regexMatch", Value: bson.D{
                                        {Key: "input", Value: "$errorMsg"},
                                        {Key: "regex", Value: primitive.Regex{Pattern: "[Uu]nable to update, apologies"}},
                                    }},
                                },
                                "Unable to update",
                                "$errorMsg",
                            }},
                        },
                    }},
                },
            }},
        }},
    }},
}
```